# Showing the NSToolbar only if hovering over the NSPanel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nstoolbar

I am making a desktop application and I want to show the `NSToolbar` of an `NSPanel` only if the mouse pointer is positioned over that `NSPanel`. Also, when the mouse pointer is **not** positioned over that `NSPanel`, the `NSToolbar` should be hidden.

Can anyone help me with detecting the hovering over the `NSPanel`, and showing and hiding the `NSToolbar` (I can only find how to toggle the `NSToolbar`)?

---

This should also happen when the application is not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup `NSTrackingArea` to see when the mouse enters/leaves the area you're interested in hovering over.